# Both Date & Time EditorFor editor in mvc razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When using @Html.EditorFor thing for date or time in mvc razor one can define a model like

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
```

or

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

however, when I change the syntax to DataType.DateTime, in my view I don't get datepicker or time mask with spinner, it just gives me a blank textbox. In my view I need something like dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm posting to the database. Is there a way to do it in mvc razor without using bootstrap datetimepicker/jquery-ui? I am using MVC5.

Comment: You can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YourProperty, new { type  "datetime-local" })` but the support is limited and you would be better of using a jquery plugin

Comment: Your best bet is a jquery plugin which will probably work cross browser.

Comment: Stephen/Bon : I too wanted to use JQuery here but this field I need is in a dynamic table and for some odd reasons the datetimepicker doesn't bind with any subsequent rows in the dynamic table except the first one.

Comment: @Poonam, Then your code is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

*Answer for 2022.*

Try using the default elements from HTML5. Add `@type = "date"` and `@type = "date"` to the `htmlAttributes`

```cs
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.TheDate)
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.TheDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { Name = "TheDate", @class = "form-control", @type = "date" } })
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.TheDate)
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.TheTime)
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.TheTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { Name = "TheTime", @class = "form-control", @type = "time" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.TheTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

What you´re doing here is adding the correct types (`type="date"`, and `type="time"`) to the HTML elements. This is the rendered result:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <label for="TheDate">Date</label>
        <input Name="TheDate" class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Enter the correct date." id="TheDate" name="TheDate" type="date" value="2022-08-18" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="TheDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <label for="TheTime">Time</label>
        <input Name="TheTime" class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Enter the correct time." id="TheTime" name="TheTime" type="time" value="10:00" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="TheTime" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What you get in the interface (using Google Chrome v104):

[image]

and

[image]